# Parameterize grafana.ini inside a configmap

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, grafana, configmap

I have a grafana dashboard running in a kubernetes cluster which is configured. yaml via a ConfigMap to use Azure AD to restrict access.

I would now like to parameterize the grafana.ini in that configmap so i can use different subdomains in my release pipeline like this:

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  grafana.ini: |
    [server]
    root_url = https://{Subdomain}.domain/
    [...]
```

{Subdomain} should be replaced in the pipeline via arguments. In a "normal" kubernetes .yaml file I can just do something like

```
[...]
host: {{ .Values.Subdomain }}.{{ .Values.Domain }}
[...]
```

to pass in arguments. This seems not to be working in the grafana.ini data section.

What is the correct syntax to pass an argument into the grafana configuration here?

Comment: Did you look on this link?: [Github parse parameters to ConfigMaps](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/741)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no string templating in YAML. The examples you are looking at are using Helm to process the YAML. You can do that, but you need actually use Helm for that.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted this as an answer as it is closest to my question/problem. However I used the information of Alireza Davoodi provided to configure my service via environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite INI config file with environment variable like this:

`export GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL= https://{Subdomain}.domain/`

You can overwrite all of the configuration options with this convention:

`GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>`

Comment: Thank you.I used the information to configure my service via environment variables.And it is working now. I acceped the answer of coderanger because it is closer to my original question.